# Converting from x12 message in java to csv in dataweave

Tags: csv, mule, mule-studio, mule-component, dataweave

I am converting the X12 input to java and then converting it into csv. While I am converting into csv I just a want few fields to be mapped. If I write the below code in dataweave then it works fine:

```
payload.Detail."2000_Loop" map {
    Provider_ID: $."0030_PRV".PRV01,
    Subscriber_Name: $."0050_SBR".SBR04
}
```

But I want to map the control number as well so when I am mapping it, it says:

```
com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException: Exception while executing: 
    payload.SetHeader.ST02 as :string,
    ^
Cannot coerce a :string to a :object
```

My code for mapping the control number along with the providerid and subscriber name is:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
[
    payload.SetHeader.ST02 as :string,

    payload.Detail."2000_Loop" map {
    Provider_ID: $."0030_PRV".PRV01,
    Subscriber_Name: $."0050_SBR".SBR04
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your case,

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv
---
flatten [
    data : payload.SetHeader.ST02 as :string,

    payload.Detail."2000_Loop" map {
    Provider_ID: $."0030_PRV".PRV01,
    Subscriber_Name: $."0050_SBR".SBR04
}
]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, but it says cannot coerce null to a string

Comment: May be some fields are null you can try with null check. Please post sample data with value changed so that I can help you more.